# What is a better way of selecting XML Nodes with different levels of hierarchy for comparing values?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am comparing two XML Nodes with the below code:

```
List<string> lolwa = new List<string>();
List<string> lolwaforever = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList subList = subListRoot.SelectSingleNode("Mainnode").SelectNodes("Subnodes");
XmlNodeList masterList = masterListRoot.SelectSingleNode("Mainnode").SelectNodes("Subnodes");
foreach (XmlNode item in subList)
    {
        lolwa.Add(item.OuterXml + item.InnerXml + item.InnerText);
    }
foreach (XmlNode item in masterList)
    {
        lolwaforever.Add(item.OuterXml + item.InnerXml + item.InnerText);
    }
match = !lolwa.Except(lolwaforever).Any(); //check if lolwa is a subset of lolwaforever
```

I need to do this process for multiple nodes, so I will have multiple masterList,subList and a foreach loop for each list. Also, as you see "Mainnode" and "Subnode" are hardcoded or will be constants.

Is there any prettier/better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how it could be implemented. I suggest to separate `IsSubsetOf` method to process `XmlNodeList` items and another overloading to process `List<XmlNodeList>` instances. Also I took a liberty to add using of `XNodeEqualityComparer` for node comparing instead of collecting strings. Notice that comparer works with classes from namespace `System.Xml.Linq`.

```
[Test]
public void CompareXmlNodeLists()
{
    // Arrange
    XmlDocument masterListRoot = new XmlDocument();
    masterListRoot.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                            <Mainnode>
                                <Subnodes id=""1"">
                                <SubChild>Child1</SubChild>
                                </Subnodes>
                                <Subnodes id=""2"">
                                <SubChild>Child2</SubChild>
                                </Subnodes>
                                <Subnodes id=""3"">
                                <SubChild>Child3</SubChild>
                                </Subnodes>
                            </Mainnode>");


    XmlDocument subListRoot = new XmlDocument();
    subListRoot.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                            <Mainnode>
                                <Subnodes id=""1"">
                                <SubChild>Child1</SubChild>
                                </Subnodes>
                                <Subnodes id=""2"">
                                <SubChild>Child2</SubChild>
                                </Subnodes>
                            </Mainnode>");

    XmlNodeList subList = subListRoot.SelectSingleNode("Mainnode").SelectNodes("Subnodes");
    XmlNodeList masterList = masterListRoot.SelectSingleNode("Mainnode").SelectNodes("Subnodes");

    // Act
    var match = IsSubsetOf(masterList, subList);
    var multipleMactch = IsSubsetOf(new List<XmlNodeList> { masterList }, new List<XmlNodeList> { subList });

    //Assert
    Assert.True(match);
    Assert.True(multipleMactch);

}

public bool IsSubsetOf(List<XmlNodeList> masters, List<XmlNodeList> subs)
{
    foreach (var sub in subs)
    {
        if (!masters.Any(x => IsSubsetOf(x, sub)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public bool IsSubsetOf(XmlNodeList master, XmlNodeList sub)
{
    XNodeEqualityComparer comparer = new XNodeEqualityComparer();
    var xSub = sub.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => XDocument.Parse(x.OuterXml));
    var xMaster = master.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => XDocument.Parse(x.OuterXml)).ToList();

    foreach (var subItem in xSub)
    {
        if (!xMaster.Any(x => comparer.Equals(x, subItem)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is a better way to check for comparison/equality. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help=)

Comment: How would you modify this to add check for equality only? (not subset) Just change !xMaster.Any to !xMaster.All?

Comment: If order is not important, you can just add checking that `master` and `sub` have equal length.